# $request->getPathInfo() returns same string for 'prod' and 'dev' environments

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am setting the current url in an action, using `$request->getPathInfo()`. However, the url retrieved is always that for the prod environment, which means that I inadvertendly move from dev to prod environment during testing.

Is there anyway to ensure that the correct URI (i.e. same as the one displayed in the browser window) is returned?.

My action code looks like this:

```
public function executeSomeAction(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->url = $request->getPathInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see inside `sfWebRequest.class.php`, `getPathInfo()` removed the `$relativeUrlRoot` from the url:

```
$pathInfo = $pathArray[$sf_path_info_key];
if ($relativeUrlRoot = $this->getRelativeUrlRoot())
{
  $pathInfo = preg_replace('/^'.str_replace('/', '\\/', $relativeUrlRoot).'\//', '', $pathInfo);
}
```

`$relativeUrlRoot` is from this function which remove the controller name from the url.

```
public function getRelativeUrlRoot()
{
  if (null === $this->relativeUrlRoot)
  {
    if (!($this->relativeUrlRoot = $this->getOption('relative_url_root')))
    {
      $this->relativeUrlRoot = preg_replace('#/[^/]+\.php5?$#', '', $this->getScriptName());
    }
  }

  return $this->relativeUrlRoot;
}
```

So if you have `myapp_dev.php/main` or `index.php/main`, you will always get `/main`.

If you want the full path **before** the `/main`, you will also have to call `$this->request->getScriptName()`.

Be careful, `getScriptName()` will return **everything** between the domain and the path info. If you have `http://exemple.com/somepath/app_dev.php/main`, `getScriptName()` will return: `/somepath/app_dev.php`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the complete URI together with any query string the address might have you can use

```
$request->getUri();
```

This will return the whole address that is visible in the browser's address bar.